# How to inner join same table with different conditions?

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I need to get contact information where employee id is null and not null. How do I join the same table with these different conditions. I need the information to populate a report with both employee information and person accompanied them to a event.  Here is the query I have so far.

```
  select events.id, (persons.firstname+' '+ persons.lastname) as employee
  from events 
  inner join eventscontacts on events.id = eventcontacts.events_id
  inner join contacts on eventcontacts.contact_id = contacts.id
  inner join persons on contacts.person_id = person.id 

Eventcontacts table 
Id  ContactType_id contact_id event_id
1   1              1          300
2   2              3          300

Contact type is 1 for employee and 2 for non emplopyees

contacts table
Id   person_id employee_id 
1    100       200
2    101       201
3    102       NULL
4    103       202
5    104       203

Person table 
Id   firstname   lastname
100  John        Stewart
101  Greg        Larry
102  Kim         Hans
103  Gloria      June
104  Dan         Duke

Result table 

ID   employee      accompany
300  John Stewart  Kim Hans
```

right now, I have information of all the employees for the event. I want the people who accompanied these person for the events. Their employee id is null in the contacts table. How do I join the contacts table again here?

Comment: Please add sample data and expected results.

Comment: Couldn't you just LEFT JOIN the `contacts` table?

Comment: I added some sample data

Comment: @HannoverFist how do I add the conditon for employee_ id is null. when I create another alias for contacts and add the condition it returns only the names of non employees.

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: @forpas I want to get information of all the employees and people who accompanied them to an event. I gave the sample results table

Comment: Check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6e331cd09579f33a0ef0b17a3ba599d6

Comment: @forpas you were right. I didnt have to join again. The employee is null value are already present but not for the same event. I dont have distinct value setup but I am not sure why

Answer (score 0):

An inner join will return only the rows that exist in both tables, where it seems like you want all the rows from the contacts table including the rows that don't match due to them lacking an employee id.

If you use an outer join, it will return rows that exist in contacts AND in events like an inner join but ALSO rows that ONLY exist in events and rows that ONLY exist in contacts.

In the case that I am explaining this poorly, I recommend you read this to help explain:

https://mode.com/sql-tutorial/sql-outer-joins/

If you can successfully use an outer join you will get all the visitors in one table regardless of having an id or not.